# Does Windows 8 have explorer.exe?

Tags: windows-8, shell, windows-explorer

I am considering buying a new laptop. I am a big fan of Windows 7 and I am reluctant moving to Windows 8. One key feature I use on Windows 7 is `explorer.exe`. Is this application still available on Windows 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`explorer.exe` is the main process that runs the Windows environment. Of course it still exists. Do you mean the classic desktop environment? That does still exist too (just make sure you aren't buying Windows RT, which is for ARM devices).

Answer (score 1):

yes it is still there in windows 8

Answer (score 1):

Explorer.exe is the Shell for Windows. It is not just an application. Without Explorer.exe you would not have most of the Windows environment (Shortcuts, desktop, Start Menu etc.)

So in short, yes it is there. Although it may have changed some depending on what functionality of the shell application you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you run 'explorer.exe' on Windows 8 you will see the explorer program, as shown below:

[image]

[image]