# What's the executable for the Windows 8.1 desktop shell?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

I have a dedicated machine that I use as Steam Box, it loads steam.exe in Big Picture mode on boot for a kiosk-ish like boot.

In Windows 7 when I needed to use the desktop I could <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> then run explorer.exe to get back into a desktop.

Doing this in Windows 8.1 doesn't fire up the desktop though, just a file explorer window. Is there a separate executable or flag to run the full blown Windows desktop?

I have tried the following

- [Startup program run before Modern UI?](https://superuser.com/questions/647698/startup-program-run-before-modern-ui/647774#647774)
- [Does Windows 8 have explorer.exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/606075/does-windows-8-have-explorer-exe/606079#606079)

Answer (score 1):

Press the `Windows key` on your keyboard to bring up the tile menu. From this menu, select the Desktop tile.

Comment: I am not in the windows desktop so the windows key does not work, I am looking for the executable I need to launch to get to the desktop, thanks anyway!

Comment: In that case, try either `Win+D` or `alt+tab`

Answer (score 0):

It's the same.  I was able to end task my shell (it disappeared), then ran "explorer.exe", and my shell returned.

Perhaps your Steam Box is configured differently.

Answer (score -1):

Try running this command:

C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{3080F90D-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}

This is the same command that is run by the "Show Desktop" link to show the desktop.